# time derivative of a time dependent function in maple

Tags: time, maple, derivative

I want to take time derivative of cos(q1) in maple such that the result will be -sin(q1)*q1_dot.

Here is what I've tried:

```
hh := sin(q1)*cos(q2):
f1 := (q1,q2) ->  hh:
f2 := diff(f1(q1,q2),q1):
f3 := diff(f2(t),t):
```

This routine does not compute d(cosq1)/dt, but leaves as it is.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the command **D(cos@q1);** Its result, when applied to **t**, will be the derivative that you are looking for.

Comment: Almost there. The result when I tried D(cos@q1) is:

    '@'(z->-sin(z),q1).D(q1)

I substitute q1_dot into D(q1) as follows:

    dd := diff(q1(t),t);
    subs(D(cos@q1),D(q1),dd)

__now, looks better. But, instead of the expression '@'(z->-sin(z),q1),  can I simply see the term sin(q1)??

Comment: Use **D(cos@q1)(t)**. You need to apply the result of **D** to **t** before it looks reasonable.